# Structure array in c not getting all of its values after reading a text file in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a homework assignment that I am working on that deals with an array of structs. Basically I have to read data from a text file (elections.txt) that looks like this and then write these names into an array of structs for names:

```
Robert Bloom
John Brown
Michelle Dawn
Michael Hall
Sean O’Rielly
Arthur Smith
Carl White
```

The code I have written so far looks like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE * data;

typedef struct
{
 int votes;
 char name[20];
}candidates;

void initialize( candidates *electionCandidates, FILE *data )
{
    int i;
    for( i=0; i<7; i++ );
    {
        fscanf( data, "%[^\n]%*c", electionCandidates[i].name );
        printf( "%s\n", electionCandidates[i].name );
    }

}

int processVotes( int p1, int p2 )
{

}

void printResults( int p1, int p2 )
{

}


int main() {
data = fopen( "elections.txt","r" );
candidates electionCandidates[7];

initialize( electionCandidates, data );


fclose( data );
return 0;
}
```

My problem is that when I run this program, what is printed on the screen is only the first name instead of all the names. I don't understand why this could be because I am looping through 7 positions of my struct array in the function. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I just saw a similar program but the question was diff. Same school I guess.

Comment: Yea its computer science at ucf. The program is called 'The Election'

Comment: `for( i=0; i<7; i++ );` : remove `;`

Comment: If I remove that then how can I put the names into the 7 different positions of my structure array?

Comment: @user3498869 look to the **right** of the word "remove" in that comment. See the `;` ? the semi-colon *after* the `')'` should not be there.

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. A debugger would immediately show you that the program doesn't loop where you think it should loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOL even I broke my head over this and I realised this is a very silly mistake

```
for( i=0; i<7; i++ ); //<- Semicolon hiding like a boss.
```

This semi-colon causes the for loop to be empty hence you are just running an empty for loop 7 times and then reading electionCandidates[7].name and printing it.Just change it to :

```
int i;
for( i=0; i<7; i++ ){
    fscanf( data, "%[^\n]%*c", electionCandidates[i].name );
    printf( "%s\n", electionCandidates[i].name );
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this but I don't have enough rep. You are EXACTLY right sir. Thank you so much.